What are 7 qubit error-correcting stabilizer codes with the 10 possible weight enumerators?
The paper https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1780 claims to find all stabilizer codes, up to equivalence, with parameters $ [[7,1,3]] $.
A few of these I can think of off the top of my head. For example the Steane code has the weight enumerator they call $ W_8=(1,0,0,0,21,0,42,0) $, with stabilizer generators
\begin{align*}
XXXXIII \\
XXIIXXI \\
XIXIXIX \\
ZZZZIII \\
ZZIIZZI \\
ZIZIZIZ
\end{align*}
and the code $ [[5,1,3]]+[[2,0,2]] $ has the weight enumerator they call $ W_1=(1,0,3,0,15,0,45,0) $ with stabilizer generators
\begin{align*}
XZZXIII \\
IXZZXII \\
XIXZZII \\
ZXIXZII \\
IIIIIXX \\
IIIIIZZ
\end{align*}
What are examples of $ [[7,1,3]] $ stabilizer codes realizing the other eight weight enumerators?
